# Do USB flash drives have a unique identifier?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

Is it possible to tell if a USB flash drives has been secretly exchanged for an identical device without inspecting the data on the device itself?

Do USB flash drives have some form of unique identification that can be copied/written down to be checked at a later date to ensure you have the same device?

Answer (score 6):

[USBDeview will show you](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) the serial number for the flash drive.

[image]

Note though, that not all USB devices [have a serial number](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041110-00/?p=37343).