# Does a format change the USB serial number?

Tags: usb, serial-number

I have read [this question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/464267/do-usb-pens-have-a-unique-identifier/464432#464432) and found that an USB stick could have a serial number associated with it. This is an intersting info for my project but I wish to know if a re-format of the USB stick could wipe away the serial number and generate a new one.
Oh well, I could try it by myself but at the moment I have no usb stick to format.

Comment: A device like a USB pen drive should have its serial number fixed in ROM/firmware.  A Harddisk partition otoh can also have sort iof serial number (UUID). Which of these are you referring to?

Comment: I am talking about an USB pen drive, something that let me always recognize the pen whenever is inserted and my application tries to read from it.

Comment: Let me clarify. "A partition on an USB pen drive can also have ..."

Comment: The firmware one. But of course, if it exists and it is possible to read it then I have the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the serial number will be stored in the firmware of the drive, which is likely read-only and set in the factory when manufactured.

It certainly wouldn't be affected by formatting the drive.

Comment: All right, finally I have managed to test a pendrive with some utilities and the SerialNumber is not changed by a format.